# Why suffixIcon does not work with river_pod?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-riverpod

I'm preparing password-field with `TextFormField`and riverpod on flutter as followings.
When the `suffixIcon` is tapped, the icon would change from solidEye to solidEyeSlash, accorging to the `bool` result of `mask`.
Actually, the bool result is toggled correctly as checked at `//here`,
however those icons never change as expected.

How should I fix my code below to let it works?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

final mask = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);

class TextFieldPassword extends ConsumerWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: TextFormField(
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 13,
          ),
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "password",//** 
            suffixIcon: IconButton(//** 
            icon: Icon(
              ref.read(mask.notifier).state // false
                ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidEye
                : FontAwesomeIcons.solidEyeSlash
                ),
            onPressed: () {
            ref.read(mask.notifier).update((state)=>!ref.read(mask.notifier).state);
            print(ref.read(mask.notifier).state);//here
            },
          ),
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219, 219),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219, 219), 
                width: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219, 219), 
                  width: 1.0, 
                )),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You like to change the icondata, therefore you need to watch the state instead of read.
`Icon(ref.watch(mask)`

```dart
icon: Icon(ref.watch(mask)  
    ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidEye
    : FontAwesomeIcons.solidEyeSlash),
```

And to update data onPressed

```dart
onPressed: () {
  final bool isVisible = ref.read(mask);
  ref.read(mask.notifier).update((state) => !isVisible);
},
```

```dart
class TextFieldPassword extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TextFieldPassword({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: TextFormField(
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 13,
          ),
          obscureText: !ref.watch(mask),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "password", //**
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(ref.watch(mask) // false
                  ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidEye
                  : FontAwesomeIcons.solidEyeSlash),
              onPressed: () {
                final bool isVisible = ref.read(mask);
                ref.read(mask.notifier).update((state) => !isVisible);
              },
            ),
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219, 219),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219, 219),
                width: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219, 219),
                  width: 1.0,
                )),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and it was really helpful for me. Should I use `ref.read()` instead of `ref.watch()`  on updating those states, even both might work.

Comment: ref.read when you just like to read for single time, and watch to get updated state, continuous data changes

Comment: I could find out the related official docs [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/)！

Comment: Well you can check [this part](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#using-refwatch-to-observe-a-provider) use watch whenever possible but inside button ref.read